# Facebook Friend List Graph API

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I get a list of friends from an user with more information about them (like relationships, birthdate, etc?)

Answer (score 1):

You can run a FQL query like:

```
SELECT uid, name, birthday, relationship_status, pic_square 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

You can add more [user fields](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) as needed.  You will need varying [extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) based on what you are trying to get.

Comment: and where do I send this query to?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need the user to accept your permission to get this data:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

as per Facebook developer guideline you can access in following ways :

```
> // Query to fetch the active user's friends, limit to 25.
>     NSString *query =
>     @"SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN "
>     @"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";
>     // Set up the query parameter
>     NSDictionary *queryParam =
>     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
>     // Make the API request that uses FQL
>     [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
>                                  parameters:queryParam
>                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"
>                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
>                                               id result,
>                                               NSError *error) {
>                               if (error) {
>                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
>                               } else {
>                                   NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
>                               }
>                           }];
```